# Why Azure Service Fabric does not deliver all messages, while local cluster does?

Tags: c#, azure, zeromq, azure-service-fabric, netmq

I am using the C# NetMQ library. I have a producer and consumer service deployed in Azure using Service Fabric stateful services. I have both services partitioned so that there are two instances of each.

The producer instances each create a `PublisherSocket` and call `Bind`. The first binds to (e.g.) `tcp://10.0.0.1:9501` and the second to `tcp://10.0.0.2:9502`. (The ports are kept unique because SF might rebalance the two instances to run on the same physical node.)

They publish to some arbitrary topic (irrevelant for this question). (I call `SendMultipartMessage` and pass it a `NetMQMessage` with several frames of data.)

The consumer instances each create a `SubscriberSocket` and call `Connect`. They each connect to both the producer addresses. They then call `Subscribe` and pass an empty string `""` as the topic. This should cause them to consume all messages sent by either producer.

Expected results:

1. Both producers bind and both consumers connect/subscribe.
2. Producer1 sends message A and Producer2 sends message B.
3. Consumer1 receives both A and B.
4. Consumer2 receives both A and B.

Actual results on **local SF cluster**: All as expected. **Both consumers receive all messages from both producers.**

Actual results on **SF cluster running on Azure**:

1. Bind/connect/subscribe all happen without exception or obvious
   error.
2. Producers send messages without error.
3. Both consumers receive messages from Producer1.
4. **Neither consumer receives messages from Producer2.**

Notes:

- Production is in a loop so this is not some odd startup issue.
- Scaling up the number of producers/consumers (e.g. 5 instances of each) results in the **first** producer's messages always being consumed, and then **some** of the other producers' messages being consumed. Approximately half of all messages get consumed, but I could not see any obvious pattern.

Questions:

1. Is there anything odd about the combination of a Service Fabric cluster running in Azure, plus ZeroMQ, that causes ZeroMQ issues?
2. Are there any ZeroMQ socket options that I should be setting?
3. Is there anything in SF that I can change?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind to review your post and add the **standard** code for the **MCVE-formulated problem**-representation to run it and repeat the above presented observations?

Comment: Can you create a sample git repository with an example to reproduce the problem? it is difficult to know the problem without knowing how you setup you application, services and the communication between them, maybe you are missing some configuration.